# Trigger pipeline with HTTP Request or fromo Power Automate flow

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, power-automate

Is there a way to trigger an Azure pipeline by using something similar to a POST call or from inside a Power Automate flow?

Similarly to how a Power Automate flow can be triggered from an HTTP Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [Run API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

as  body if you want to trigger build on main branch use this json

```
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/main"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you don't know how to authenticate this documentation explain you how to use [PAT token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)